Could not find accessor com.example.checkd.viewmodels.StockViewModel.entropy Open File (Android Studio)
public class StockViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<Entropy> entropy = new MutableLiveData<>(new Entropy());

    private AlphaVantageService alphaVantageService;
    private NewsApiService newsApiService;

    public StockViewModel() {
        alphaVantageService = RetrofitClient.getAlphaVantageService();
        newsApiService = RetrofitClient.getNewsApiService();
    }

    @Bindable
    public LiveData<Entropy> getEntropy() {
        return entropy;
    }


I've tried just about everything. The idea is it's supposed to make an api call, use the metadata to retrieve a name, and use the name as an ID...
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_stock_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@{stockViewModel.entropy.stockName != null ? stockViewModel.entropy.stockName : @string/default_stock_name}"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

This is the API call...
public Entropy() {
    alphaVantageService = RetrofitClient.getAlphaVantageService();
}

public void fetchStockName(String symbol, StockViewModel stockViewModel) {
    Call<StockSearchResponse> call = alphaVantageService.searchStockBySymbol(symbol, Constants.ALPHA_VANTAGE_API_KEY);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<StockSearchResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<StockSearchResponse> call, Response<StockSearchResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                String stockName = response.body().getBestMatch().get(0).getName();
                stockViewModel.setStockName(stockName);
            } else {
                // Handle API error
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<StockSearchResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            // Handle network error
        }
    });
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
